# Generate a PDF with FPDF with content from django-website

Tags: django, pdf, django-views, fpdf

I'm trying to run a Python code that are using the FPDF- library to produce a pdf with some simple text.

```
def example(request):
    ....
    generatePDF(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)
    ...
    return HttpResponse("PDF generated")

def generatePDF(x,y,z):
    import fpdf from FPDF

    pdf = FPDF

    pdf = FPDF('L", "mm", "A4")

    pdf.addpage()
    ...
    ...
    ...

    pdf.output("test.pdf", "F")
```

The Django code without the function, run perfectly and smoothly, and the function for  PDF- production runs without problem when I call it in the terminal.

But when I try to use the PDF function inside a Django view, I only get an Error 500 in return.

Why is this happening?